# What is the right way to assign a unique id to request in Slim framework 3?

Tags: slim

I am using slim framework 3 for my app.

I need suggestion on how could I implement the process of generating a unique id or request id for every request and then showing that unique id in the response.

My purpose is basically to provide a unique id to every request and saving that id in database and finally showing that id with processed data to user, so user can query on basis of that id next time.

What I have understood so far is, I should done this by using middleware.

I have created a function of processing data say: processed_data in class .

My routes is :

```
$app->group('/products', function() {
        new \Products($this);

});


 class Products
    {
        public function __construct($app)
        {
            $app->map(['GET','POST'], '/processed_data', [$this, 'processed_data']);
            $c = $app->getContainer();
        }


        public function processed_data($request, $response, $next){

                    $data = array('name' => 'Bob', 'age' => 40);            

        /* I need to append $data in $response or in any container,
        instead of writting here using write() method so that I 
        can use my $data in middleware for final processing or 
        simply say adding a unique id with this $data.*/

                    return $response;

                 }

    }
```

Middleware I created is:

```
   class SendStandardResponse
    {
        public function __construct(){} 


        public function get_standard_request($request, $response, $next) {

        // here I saved the request in the database 
         /*I want here to generate a unique id say : XXXXXX .
        I am not sure where to append this unique id, either in 
        request or response or container. */

            return $request;
        }


        /**
         * recode_Response
         */
        public function send_stardard_esponse($request, $response, $next) {

            // here I saved the response in the database    
            /* get the output data from the processed_data function and add the unique id to response .
            And finally send the response with $data and unique id by merging /

            $data = array('name' => 'Bob', 'age' => 40, 'requestid' => 'xxxxxx');

            and send it with response

            */

             return $response;
        }



        public function __invoke($request, $response, $next)
        {   

            $this->get_standard_request($request, $response, $next);

            $response = $next($request, $response);

            $this->send_stardard_esponse($request,$response, $next);    

            return $response;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're absolutely correctly want to implement it using middlewares.
However, I suggest you don't use one middleware, but two: one for generating and appending ID to request object, another (which is invoked after action) is for storing response and associated ID. This will make your code easier to read and maintain. Just keep ID as request attribute.

Probably something like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * This middleware generates and appends unique ID
 */
class IdHandlingMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Object constructor
     * 
     * We're passing generator as argument so that 
     * ID generation logic - however simple it is
     * is encapsulated in a separate class.
     */
    public function __construct(IdGenerator $generator)
    {
        $this->IdGenerator = $generator;
    }

    /**
     * Invoke middleware
     * 
     * Generate ID, add it to response attributes and 
     * invoke next callable.
     * 
     * Note it's throwing an exception if ID generator failed.
     * I don't know how critical this ID system for you is.
     * 
     */
    public function __invoke($request, $response, $next)
    {
        if ($id = $this->IdGenerator->generateUniqueId()) {
            $request = $request->withAttribute('uniqueId');
        } else {
            throw new \Exception('Failed to generate unique ID');
        }
        return $next($request, $response);
    }
}

/**
 * This class records response and associated ID
 */
class ResponseRecordingMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Again, let's inject some kind of recorder,
     * so we don't mix persistence layer and application layer.
     * Keep things separated.
     */
    public function __construct(Recorder $recorder)
    {
        $this->recorder = $recoder;
    }

    /**
     * Record the response.
     * 
     * Note I pass two arguments to Recorder::record:
     * - response object
     * - request ID that is contained as request attribute.
     */
    public function __invoke($request, $response, $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request, $response);
        $this->recorder->record($response, $request->getAttribute('uniqueId'));
        return $response;
    }
}

/**
 * And don't forget to register these middlewares.
 * Note the order of adding.
 */

$app->add(ResponseRecordingMiddleware::class)->add(IdHandlingMiddleware::class);
```